# Instead of k-fold cross validation, why not just randomize the random_state?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Before I knew about k-fold cross validation, I would just set a random_state like so:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
    y,
    random_state=np.random.randint(1000),
    test_size=0.25)
```

Then, I would iterate over this a bunch of times, storing my accuracy measures and then compute a confidence interval on that array.

Is there any downside to doing this?

Comment: Here's a [post on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51416/k-fold-vs-monte-carlo-cross-validation) that might answer your question.

Comment: What you refer to is actually called Monte Carlo cross-validation (google it)...

Comment: Ahh perfect. Thanks!